# How do I add the "title" attribute to Drupal's form element?

Tags: forms, drupal

I need to add a "title" attribute in HTML to Drupal's form element. How should I do that using the form API?

Comment: Do you want to add the "title" attribute to `<form>`?

Answer (score 3):

Did You tried **#attributes** property ?

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#attributes